# Please provide a mobile-optimized captcha page

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, captcha

When working with the mobile version of one of the mobile sites, my connection got really slow, and (I think this is what) caused Apple.SE to show me a captcha. I'm okay with that, but  I'd like to point out that the mobile site should have a mobile optimized captcha.

With slow internet connections in mind, I suggest to implement a mobile-optimized captcha page.

Comment: As if Captchas weren't hard enough on mobile =P

Comment: @BenBrocka - Actually, I suspect that there may be a way to force iOS and possibly android to disable autocorrect with HTML attributes but I'm not sure.

Comment: I was thinking more of the general interaction of typing, interesting if you can do that though, I'll have to look it up. Haven't heard of a good mobile captcha platform but a search found some interesting brainstorming: http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~alsmola/sp10/info213/mobilecaptcha/

Comment: @BenBrocka - Great find.

Comment: +1 I've found this happens to me a lot when I first try to submit and it gets rejected (usually when it rejects a new tag because auto-correct got the tag name wrong). It could also be the slow connection, though.