# Make Captcha testing page mobile friendly

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no mobile version of the captcha page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111708/why-is-there-no-mobile-version-of-the-captcha-page)

Sometimes, I am presented "Are you human?" page when I do something quick. Its OK, but when I am on smartphone, the page is still displayed in desktop formatting. Please, make captcha testing page mobile friendly.